# Replace ACT- and PWR-Led on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, board-leds

I somehow broke off the ACT- and the PWR-Leds from my Raspberry Pi 3.
It's still working fine, but i want to solder some new ones on.
What kind of Led do i need?

[image: Picture of the non existing ACT- and PWR-Leds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [schematics](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf) available at [www.raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings) we learn that the LED's package size is SMD 1611. I assume that is the metric code which corresponds to the imperial size of 0605. Given the resistors of 470 ohms any LED with a forward current of about or a little less than 5 mA should do.

[image]
<sup><sub>[Source](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf)</sub></sup>